# Set FOSRestBundle Exception _format

Tags: json, exception, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am using FOSRestBundle in my Symfony 2.3 project.

I am not able to set _format for response exceptions.
In my config.yml I have:

```
twig:
    exception_controller: 'FOS\RestBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::showAction'
```

Default return is HTML format, but
is it possible to set `_format = json` to return exceptions?

I have more than one bundle, but only one is RestBundle, so other bundles need to set in normal way.

Comment: did you clear your cache after changing config.yml ?

Comment: I always do it after changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your routes manually and set `_format` there like this:

```
acme_demo.api.user:
    type: rest
    pattern: /user/{username_canonical}.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: 'AcmeDemoBundle:User:getUser', username_canonical: null, _format: json }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
```

**Edit**: Or you can write your own exception handler and do with exceptions whatever you need to do:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/EventListener/AcmeExceptionListener.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

class AcmeExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // do whatever tests you need - in this example I filter by path prefix
        $path = $event->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
        if (strpos($path, '/api/') === 0) {
            return;
        }

        $exception = $event->getException();
        $response = new JsonResponse($exception, 500);

        // HttpExceptionInterface is a special type of exception that
        // holds status code and header details
        if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
            $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
            $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
        }

        // Send the modified response object to the event
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

And register it as a listener:

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\AcmeExceptionListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

[How to create an Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)

Comment: In my routing config, for all Restful methods I have `_format: json`. Problem is, that default format for Exceptions is `html` and I don't known how to change it.

Comment: I've added a link to tutorial on custom exception handling. Setting a Response in the listener (as shown in example) makes Symfony return it.

Comment: Thank you. It may be helpful, but how to use this class of exception to RestBundle Service, and the rest left unchanged?

Comment: Leave the controllers unchanged, in custom `kernel.exception` event listener check if you want to handle that exception (e.g. check for some route match or path prefix). If you want to handle the exception process it and set a Response, otherwise do nothing and exception will be handled as usually.

Comment: @tomas.pecserke, `strpos()` expects at least 2 arguments.

Comment: Note, `strpos()` should be compared against `false` rather than `0`. String positions start counting at 0 instead of 1, so 0 is returned when a match is found. See the note below in the "Return Values" section:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: @Sheraz the example listens only for non-API request, therefore the condition checks if the path starts with '/api/' and if so returns

Comment: I don't have "API"-routes. I just have REST resources. Some are JSON, some are XML and others are HTML. (Yes a REST-API can also serve HTML resources). The exception  handler should respect that resource format. Is this possible? Also it seems that this handler prevents logging of exceptions. Is the only way to add a custom log message myself?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method to catch symfony exceptions and return a json when a request is made to a FosRest Controller is the following:

```yaml
# app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api/', priorities: ['json', 'xml'] }
            - { path: '^/', stop: true }
```